# Align Button to bottom of Flexbox Container

Tags: css, flexbox

I created a Flexbox layout of three cards and want the buttons in each card to align to center, bottom. Is this possible? Can I use CSS Grid to do this?

```
[Codepen Example][1]
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/art852/project/editor/AMWreY#0

Comment: Take a look at this guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: If you set the `flex-item` div to also be `display:flex;` and add a `flex-direction: column;` property, you can have the button always appear at the same level, across all the boxes. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for a good guide on flex

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use CCS Grid, but the comment from S Grimminck worked for what I was trying to achieve. Down voters are absolutely no help at all.